# postgresql re-write OR Part in query to improve performance

Tags: postgresql, exists, postgresql-performance, where-in, not-exists

I'm trying to re-write below query to improve performance. Query has Distinct on and query is slow because of OR part has two sub queries for same products table (so twice scanning) for the each key in category table.

```
-- original query
select Distinct on (p.value,c.key) c.key, c.type_key, c.status, c.created_by 
from category c
LEFT JOIN products p
on p.category_key=c.key
where c.type_key=4  
and p.status='active' and c.status='active'
and p.attribute_key=6
and ( 
   (EXISTS (SELECT * from products p1
                  WHERE p1.attribute_key=2 
                   AND p1.category_key=c.key 
                   AND ((value in ('Active', 'active')))
                   AND p1.status='active'
        ))
    OR(NOT EXISTS(SELECT * from products p1
                   WHERE p1.attribute_key=2 
                    AND p1.category_key=c.key 
                    AND p1.status='active') 
        )) 
order by p.value
```

Query returns keys from category table if type_key=4 and category.status='active' and attribute_key=6 and

1. products table has  attribute_key=2 and value='Active' or 'active' and status='active. (this is EXISTS  part in sub-query)
2. even if products table doesn't have any attribute_key or has attribute_key!=2 records for type_key=4. (this is OR( NOT EXISTS)  part in sub-query)

Sample data is here [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=fede44bac687f478f4abc4838c702cfa)

Since  predicates on the products table are almost same. I tried re-write and below is my latest query

```
select Distinct on (p.value,c.key) c.key, c.type_key, c.status, c.created_by 
from category c
LEFT JOIN products p
on p.category_key=c.key
where c.type_key=4  
and p.attribute_key in (2,6) 
and p.status='active' and c.status='active'
and  (p.attribute_key !=2 -- NOT EXISTS
   OR (value in ('Active', 'active'))) 
order by p.value
```

But latest query returns some duplicates even though there is Distinct ON.

[image]

Is it possible to improve original query by writing another way or changing OR part in query

Comment: You query is not producing duplicates for the columns within `Distinct on`. The issue is that your selection list does not contain the column 'value' despite it being in the distinct on. See revision on your fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0f7e4251ca37b7833fc1e486f83db555). It includes the `value` column and shows that it is indeed distinct on the columns actually used.

Comment: Thanks @Belayer , after value column added in select, I can see revision query result completely different with original query.
May be revision query is not giving expected result.